# Multiple Failed to read Sector - Unrecovered Read Error" when backing up dvd. Tried multiple copies of the same dvd

Tags: hard-drive, backup, dvd, iso-image, dvd-burning

I've been backing up my dvd collection to external drives which are connected to a raspberry pi running kodi.

I've literally backed up thousands of dvds without any issue but I'm having a real problem with disc 1,6 & 8 of The young indiana jones chronicles volume 2.

I've tried the following programs all of which either fail while analysing, or fail during the reading or I've just left running for a few days at which point it's only moved 1 or 2 percent and I've just quit it:

- dvd decrypter
- any dvd
- DVDFab
- DVD Shrink
- IsoBuster
- IsoPuzle
- CloneDVD
- WinX Dvd Ripper
- Magic ISO
- Win Iso
- ImgBurn

I've tried 3 different computers with 3 different dvd drives but for those 3 dvds it gets to around 40% and then just hangs or takes a day to move a percent

In dvd decrypter I've set the retries to 0 so it moves to the next sector, it's been running 18 hours and has almost 10,000 errors like:

> W 11:17:22 Failed to read Sector 1768687 - Unrecovered Read Error

The dvds play fine using power dvd or through my dvd player and from what I've read this can happen; the dvds can be fine but tiny scratches or imperfections can cause bad sectors that are unreadable(Which is why I tried ISOBuster)

This is the final box set I need to back up so I thought I'll just buy it again and everything will be fine, unfortunately this was not the case and this copy has the exact same issues at the same section of the dvd, I got this other copy of eBay so its not like my local store got sent a dodgy batch of dvds that I've had the misfortune in buying.

I know these dvds can be backed up because I found a torrent where these dvds were ripped to iso but they were compressed. Can anybody suggest any reason why I'm getting this issue and any way I can create a back up of these discs?

I've cleaned the discs (even used the toothpaste trick) and I have a dvd cleaner that I've used on all 3 drives.